# During what part of an HTTP request can the protocol get stuck?

Tags: python, http

```py
import python_http_client # 3.2.1

client = python_http_client.Client(host='https://www.google.com')

while True:
    print(client.get()) # Has no request timeout
```

With this piece of code, the HTTP client gets stuck and hangs if I disconnect and reconnect my internet. Is this a bug with the package that I'm using or is this something that's inherently possible with HTTP protocol?

Comment: You're missing `.call.get()` by the looks of it. Ah, and this is for REST api. not normal HTTP requests.

Comment: TCP is fault-tolerant. If there's a network interruption it keeps retrying for a while before reporting an error, in case it's a temporary problem.

Comment: maybe it's the keep alive option in the http protocol

Comment: have you tried using requests instead? https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: If you’re using an external library, why not try `requests`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `python_http_client.Client` can take a timeout in seconds, like

```
client = python_http_client.Client(host='https://www.google.com', timeout=30)
```

Citation: https://github.com/sendgrid/python-http-client/blob/d99717c9e48f07a1a7d598e657838070704b4da7/python_http_client/client.py#L75